# Unable to close download notification(after successfully download) in mozilla firefox through selenium python 3

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, firefox, cross-browser, python-3.7

Selenium Version = 3.141,
Mozilla Firefox Version : 101.0.1
Automation Framework : Pytest

After successfully downloading the file, we want the notification to be closed.

I am able to download the file, but unable to perform any operation because of the notification that appears at the right top of the mozilla firefox browser. I want to close that notification through selenium code but it seems not working.

Have tried following solutions:

```
      options = webdriver.FirefoxOptions()
    # options = FirefoxProfile()
      options.set_preference("dom.webnotifications.enabled", False)
      options.set_preference("dom.push.enabled", False)
      options.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk","application/pptx, application/csv, application/ris, text/csv, image/png, application/pdf, text/html, text/plain, application/zip, application/x-zip, application/x-zip-compressed, application/download, application/octet-stream")

      options.set_preference("browser.download.panel.shown", False)

      options.set_preference("browser.download.folderList", 2)
      options.set_preference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting", False)
      options.set_preference("browser.download.dir", os.path.join(parent_folder, 'Downloads'))
      options.set_preference("browser.download.manager.closeWhenDone", True)
      options.set_preference("browser.download.manager.showAlertOnComplete", False)
    # options.add_argument("--headless")
    # options.headless = True
      web_driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_options=options,executable_path=GeckoDriverManager().install())
```

- Solution 2:

After successfully downloading the file, we are trying to press ESC key to dismiss the notification but this also seems not working

```
self.driver.find_element_by_tag_name('body').send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + Keys.ENTER)
```

OR

```
ActionChains(self.driver).send_keys(Keys.ESCAPE).perform()
```

- Solution 3

Tried to Refresh the screen as well, but notification is still there.

Image is attached below:

File is being successfully downloaded but unable to close this notification through selenium python.

[image: Firefox Download Notification]

Comment: Can you ensure that the _...Image is attached for the reference..._

Comment: Hey, sorry, it was missed, now successfully uploaded. Please click on the link above 'Firefox Download Notification'.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the incorrect MIME type for pptx, so that **may** be causing the notification to hang around, so do following update to see if it resolves the issue:

**from** `application/pptx`
**to** `application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation`

More info on MIME types can be found here: [Common MIME types - HTTP | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types/Common_types)

**UPDATE**

Mozilla has introduced changes from Firefox 97+, one of them is to the download panel and the behaviour is what you experienced. For selenium purposes, you can stop the panel from opening using the following option:

```
options.set_preference("browser.download.alwaysOpenPanel", False)
```

Comment: It seems not working even after changing 'application/pptx' to 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation'

Comment: @Abhishek - think I have found your solution, updated answer above

Comment: Thank you @djmonki for the update, will check the solution you provided above and update you if it works :-) thanks !